# Permutation for options and ways to handle it

Tags: algorithm, rendering, data-representation

I found myself with a problem that I can't seem to figure out a good way to handle it.

Basically I have 4 options and for all permutations of the options i have a collection that I want to sort them into. So something like:

```
 bool A, B, C, D
```

to be sorted into:

```
 Map A, AB, AC, AD, ABC, ABD, ABCD...
```

so AB = BA, so not **all** permutations, but a representation of each combination.

*So why do I want this mapping?*

Basically A, B, C And D is GBuffer channels in a deferred renderer, and I want to tell the shader which buffers to use. Binding the shader render targets is expensive, and that is why I want too keep the permutations as separate collections. So I can do one binding per permutation.

So, the problem..

What I do now to sort the options into categories is that I simply check like this:

```
if (A) {
    if (B) {
        if (C) {
            if (D) {
                return ABCD;
            } else {
                return ABC;
            }
        } else {
            if (D) {
                return ABD;
```

and so on..

I feel that first of all it's tricky to say the least to know that all permutations are being handled the correct way, not to mention what happens if I would like to utilize one more pass of the buffer, (I am not sure why but it's not all that far fetched, perhaps not another pass in the gbuffer but perhaps another option for something else).

Point is that it would grow a lot.

The option I guess is to not store the permutations in different collections, however than I will have to do a buffer rebind on every single one (worst case). Nor I am doing something like this:

```
bind buffer for A
for each (a in A) {draw a}

bind buffer for AB
for each (ab in AB) {draw b}
```

and so on, if I don't store them in different collections I would turn it around and get:

```
for each (b in buffers) {
    bind buffer according to b
    draw b
}
```

I.e. lots of rebinds, which are expensive and not really an option.

I hope it isn't too unclear now and that my reasoning is easy enough to follow. So I would like to figure out a better way to handle this but still do as little re-binds as possible, perhaps there is some way I just haven't thought about if I re-think how to represent the permutations or something like that. But I thought I might as well ask here in hope that someone has some good ideas about this problem domain.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: If you just want all the possible combinations of k elements, look at the binary representation of 1 to 2^k - 1. E.g., 0001, 0010, 0011, 0100, ..., with the set bits representing inclusion.

Comment: ahh, that is not a bad idea. Would make it easier since an OR combination will map to the buffertype without the conversionstep.

Comment: These are combinations, not permutations.